# Как загрузить аудиофайл в SoundPool c SD карты?

Tags: java, android

Подготавливаю:

```
private static SoundPool soundPool;
private static HashMap<Integer, Integer> soundPoolMap;

soundPool = new SoundPool(2, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 100);
    soundPoolMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>(3);
```

Как загрузить из ресурса я понял (строка ниже)

```
    soundPoolMap.put( S1, soundPool.load(context, R.raw.s1, 1) );
```

А как положить туда файл с SD карты?

Сам файл подготавливаю так:

```
File FileOut = new File(getExternalFilesDir(path), file_out);
```

Вообще задача следующая: есть аудио файлы (wav формат) на sd карте. Нужно их воспроизвести в определенном порядке. Порядок будет в виде плэйлиста. И еще, пауз между воспроизведениями файлов быть не должно, т.е. закончился один, сразу начинается другой.

Возможно эту задачу можно решить и не прибегая к SoundPool. Что посоветуете?

Answer (score 1):

Если больше ничего не помогает - загляните наконец в документацию )))     [`SoundPool.load(String path, int priority)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html#load(java.lang.String,%20int))

Comment: Не получается. Кладу файл: soundPoolMap.put(1, soundPool.load(FileOut.getCanonicalPath(), 1)); Запускаю файл: soundPool.play(soundPoolMap.get(1), volume, volume, 1, 0, 1f);

Comment: Что именно не получается? Ошибки какие? Про разрешения на доступ к файлам не забыли? Если звуки больше 5-ти секунд, то `SoundPool ` Вам вообще не подходит. И ещё загрузка может занимать время и плей сразу не сработать - тогда нужно использовать [`SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener.html)

Comment: разрешения есть, не проходит проверку if(soundPool == null || soundPoolMap == null) и звуки больше 5 секунд. Наверно в длительности проблема.

Comment: У Вас проблемы с последовательностью действий, раз переменные не инициализированы. На длинных треках он будет просто играть начало (несколько секунд) и всё. Тогда надо использовать [`MediaPlayer`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html).

Comment: Да, я уже перешел на MediaPlayer, т.к. файлы большие и SoundPool не подходит.